# python time timer stuck on zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, time, while-loop

I am trying to start a timer inside of a validation within a while loop.

i.e.

```
if(foo):
   start_time
```

I'm expect it to print incremental time but it just prints zeros and to continue counting even after being checked once.

Code:

```
warning_timer = 0

while True:
        if warning_timer == 0:
                start_time = time.time()
                warning_timer = 1
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)))
```

output:

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

How do I use the time library to print out an incremental time?

Comment: Have you waited for >1 second to pass?

Comment: What is a ‘validation’ - please explain in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The timer resets in every loop iteration, so just putting out the initialization should be good.

```py
import time
warning_timer = 0

if warning_timer == 0:
    start_time = time.time()
while True:
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)))
```

In case you need use start timer several times inside loop, the thing is that as no operation is made between start and end time, no elapsed time is shown. You can try with this example.

```py
from random import randint
import time

warning_timer = 0

while True:
    if warning_timer == 0:
        start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(randint(1, 4))
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your post let me know I was doing something else wrong. I see you have a new account so I'll throw in a bonus.

Comment: Thanks, I also added example to show an elapsed time between start and end time using sleep function.

Comment: Thank you again. What is the purpose of the randint(1,4) inside of sleep?

Comment: Function randint generates a random value between first and second value. In this case is used to show a random time elapsed between start and end interval.

Comment: When I remove the random, I get zeros again. Clocks are typically incremental, not random.

Comment: Yes, it was an example. As between start time and end time no time consuming task is done, it is almost 0 seconds

Comment: Why does the clock reset to zero every cycle? My issue is that I need the timer to continue following a while cycle. Never terminating unless I tell it to stop.

Comment: Then i think first snippet of both in post answers your question

Comment: The first snippet is doing the same thing as my OP. I should be able to slap it into a file, run it and watch it count. Clocks are better but conting will work, with some nasty hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting out unnecessary code, just initialize start_time before entering the while True loop:

```
start_time = time.time()
while True:
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))
```

NOTEyou’ll have to wait at least a second to get beyond 00:00:00 to 00:00:01

Comment: In order for it to work, start_time has to be behind a validation. i.e. if(foo){start_time}

Comment: No I don’t understand. You haven’t previously mentioned `validation`. Please explain this new requirement in your question.

Comment: It the first line in the OP "I am trying to start a timer inside of a validation within a while loop."

Comment: Please explain in your question what ‘validation’ means

Comment: if(foo){start_time}. if is a validation

Comment: No `foo` in your question.

Comment: if warning_timer == 0: in my question

Comment: OK you mean a condition. The problem is that `warning_timer` is never changed from zero, so inevitably the `start_time` in your’validation’ is always reintialized every time round the loop resulting in printing 00:00:00 ad infinitum. If you want something different than 00:00:00 you will have to make sure the ‘validation’ condition is only satisified __once__.

Comment: throw it into your answer. That was it.